# Which is more accurate Browserstack or F12

Tags: css, ie-developer-tools, browserstack, ie8-browser-mode

I am getting different results when looking at ie8 in Browserstack and the F12 developer tools in ie11. Which would be a more accurate representation and why?

Comment: Different results of what? More accurate representation of what?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but it was intentional. I didn’t want to go into what was different because I didn’t want an answer about how to resolve the potential issue, that I can do, it’s was a simple question about which was better for testing. PoeHaH has given me that answer I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

A native browser is always better than the simulated result via the developers tools.
I would trust IE8 in Browserstack more than IE11 dev tools.

One example why:

> It is worth noting that IE 9 shipped with a newer JavaScript engine,
>   called Chakra. While the browser itself supports a number of
>   compatibility modes, because the JavaScript engine itself differs
>   significantly from what shipped with IE 6, 7 and 8, there are
>   acknowledged differences between the experience in IE 9 and testing in
>   a standalone browser.

As found in this article:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/